# What is two different expression to saying that she had to fulfill her promise in the future?

Tags: phrase-request

What is two different expression to saying that she had to fulfill her promise in the future?

For example, she had made a promise to buy me gift later, and so the question follows.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking here.  What is wrong with "She had to fulfill her promise"? Or what is wrong with "She promised" Some further clarification would help.

Comment: @JamesK  I can't see that there's anything wrong with asking for synonymous expressions.  I'm just curious why Victor asked for only *two* of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why *two*?  Is this for a homework assignment?  No matter.

> 1. You **owe it to me** to [do the thing you promised]
> 2. You **are obligated** to [do the thing you promised]

Do you want more than two?  I can give you more.